# YouTube upload from VB.NET with V3 API

Tags: google-api, youtube.net-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Anyone familiar with the V3 YouTube API suggest what I might be doing wrong:

```
    Dim Service As YoutubeService = GetYouTubeService()

    Dim SourceVideo As String = "C:\TempMedia\Wildlife.wmv"

    Dim Meta As New Video
    Meta.Snippet = New VideoSnippet
    Meta.Snippet.Title = "Test Wildlife Video"
    Meta.Snippet.Description = "This is a test video only"
    Meta.Snippet.CategoryId = "Animals"
    Meta.Snippet.Tags = New List(Of String)
    Meta.Snippet.Tags.Add("Test")
    Meta.Status = New VideoStatus
    Meta.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"

    Using fs As New FileStream(SourceVideo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Inheritable)
        Dim UploadRequest As VideosResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Videos.Insert(Meta, "snippet,statistics,status", fs, "application/octet-stream")
        UploadRequest.Upload()
        Dim Uploaded = UploadRequest.ResponseBody
    End Using
```

After thinking for a bit, this is throwing a 500 Internal Server Error in the SendChunk

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233079   Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.   Source=System   StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.SendChunk(Stream stream, Uri uri, Int64 position) in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 452
       at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.Upload() in c:\code.google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\BuildRelease\bin\Debug\12-20-2012\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 315
       at QUICTools.Workflow.Social.YouTube.QuicYouTube.TestUpload() in C:\Users\kenny.munro.ZAZA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\QUIC_V2.0\QUICTools.Workflow.Social.YouTube\QuicYouTube.vb:line 37
       at QLTest.Form1.SimpleButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\kenny.munro.ZAZA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\QUIC_V2.0\QLTest\Form1.vb:line 4
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at QLTest.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

I have to admit I'm now stumped.  Does anyone have a working example of an upload to YouTube using the V3 dotnet API or suggestions where this might be going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've been doing some more analysis of this using Fiddler.  First, I set added a line to set the chunkSize = 10000.  I can now see loads of chunks being uploaded just fine and returning 308 response codes.  The error is being returned by the final partial chunk:

```
PUT /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=AEnB2UqVVIYV1YyYk27JhhFj_U2WzbK0_ghq0QIRsO1dB1caaMrazd-wlULFZVxvM_pHDZFJkVmUJbYw4oVicI2rfJujdXy4ZQ HTTP/1.1
Content-Range: bytes 26250000-26255829/26255830
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 5830

500 Internal Server Error (application/json)
```

Not too sure how this could be anything I'm doing wrong but would appreciate some input/validation from someone who has this working.

For completeness, here's the initial insert command - again, all looks fine to me:

```
POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus HTTP/1.1
X-Upload-Content-Type: video/x-ms-wmv
X-Upload-Content-Length: 26255830
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHES6ZTQsUz4SI-jOnCO8kL3hg_L...
Content-Type: application/json
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 168
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"snippet":{"categoryId":"Entertainment","description":"This is a test video only","tags":["Test"],"title":"Test Wildlife Video"},"status":{"privacyStatus":"unlisted"}}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Feb 6 2013 15:53:54 (1360194834)
Location: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&part=snippet%2Cstatus&upload_id=AEnB2UqVVIYV1YyYk27JhhFj_U2WzbK0_ghq0QIRsO1dB1caaMrazd-wlULFZVxvM_pHDZFJkVmUJbYw4oVicI2rfJujdXy4ZQ
Date: Tue, 19 Feb 2013 13:58:18 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Can no-one offer any feedback on this?  Does it work for anyone else or is it a bug that I need to raise with Google?

Comment: Could you please post your GetYouTubeService() method?

Answer (score 1):

CategoryId is a number. You can use this example to download a list of the ID (number) and the Title of all of the valid categories. This example puts the ID and Title into a custom class object and adds each class object as an item in a ComboBox control.

```
    OAUth2Credential = Nothing
    Try
        GetGredentials.Wait()
        objYouTubeService = New YouTubeService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
             .HttpClientInitializer = OAUth2Credential, _
             .ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name})
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End
    End Try
    Dim objCategories As VideoCategoryListResponse = Nothing
    Try
        Dim objRequest As VideoCategoriesResource.ListRequest = New VideoCategoriesResource.ListRequest(objYouTubeService, "id,snippet")
        objRequest.Hl = "en_US"
        objRequest.RegionCode = "US"
        objCategories = objRequest.Execute
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "Title"
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "Id"
    For Each obj As VideoCategory In objCategories.Items
        cmbCategory.Items.Add(New CategoryClass(obj.Id, obj.Snippet.Title))
        If obj.Snippet.Title.Contains("News") Then
            intDefaultCategoryIndex = cmbCategory.Items.Count - 1
        End If
    Next
    cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = intDefaultCategoryIndex
    ...
```

Below is how I fill OAuth2Credential.

```
Private Async Function GetGredentials() As Task
     Try
         '
         ' ClientId and ClientSecret are found in your client_secret_*****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json file downloaded from 
         ' the Google Developers Console ( https://console.developers.google.com). 
         ' This sample shows the ClientID and ClientSecret in the source code. 
         ' Other samples in the sample library show how to read the Client Secrets from the              ' client_secret_*****.apps.googleusercontent.com.json file. 
         '
         OAUth2Credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( _
             New ClientSecrets With {.ClientId = "Your Client ID goes here ..............................................", _
                                     .ClientSecret = "Your Client Secret goes here."}, _
                                 {YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube}, "user", CancellationToken.None)
         If OAUth2Credential IsNot Nothing Then
             If OAUth2Credential.Token IsNot Nothing Then
                 AddToLog(String.Concat("Token Issued: ", OAUth2Credential.Token.Issued))
             End If
         End If
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Google Authorization")
         End
     End Try
 End Function
```

This is what my custom class looks like:

```
Friend Class CategoryClass
Dim m_Id As String
Dim m_Title As String
Sub New(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Title As String)
     m_Id = Id
     m_Title = Title
End Sub
Property ID As String
      Get
         ID = m_Id
     End Get
     Set(value As String)
         m_Id = value
     End Set
End Property
Property Title As String
     Get
         Title = m_Title
     End Get
     Set(value As String)
         m_Title = value
     End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Could you please show me how you build the OAUth2Credential varible

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I was out of the country without a PC. 

I modified my answer to include the **GetCredentials** subroutine. This code is from my example program found in my tip [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801604/Sample-VB-NET-program-using-Google-APIs-for-NET-V).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are uploading by chunks why don't you capture the progress and responsereceived events so you can have more info of what's happening. Here's how you can do it:

```
UploadRequest.ChunkSize = 10000;
UploadRequest.ProgressChanged += UploadRequest_ProgressChanged;
UploadRequest.ResponseReceived += UploadRequest_ResponseReceived;

Sub UploadRequest_ProgressChanged(obj As Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress)
    ' check if the upload has been completed            
    If obj.Status = Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Completed Then
        ' do something here
    End If

    ' or check the status and handle it appropriately
    ' see "Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus" for possible status returned


    ' or check the details of the exception here
    If obj.Exception IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Exception.Message)
    End If
End Sub

Sub UploadRequest_ResponseReceived(Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data.Video obj)
    ' your video object will be available here once the upload is done

End Sub
```

*NOTE: I wrote this in C# and used a site to convert it to VB so there may be some syntax error, I'm sure you know how to fix it.*