# Error uploading videos to youtube (YouTube API v3 - Visual Basic .NET Project w/v3 DLLs)

Tags: vb.net, video, upload, youtube-api

I've ran in to some trouble trying to upload videos to YouTube trough the V3 API. I've tried to upload asynchroniously like stated in the following sample:
[YouTube upload from VB.NET with V3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941646/youtube-upload-from-vb-net-with-v3-api)

But now I'm running into errors wich I cannot explain.
I've set the chunk-size to 100000 and the upload works fine (events are fired) - but after two or three event fires I'm getting the following error:
Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.

I've tried to upload the video file w/o chunk-size to check if the error persists - in this case I get the following error:
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Thanks for any help!
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug and see that you opened the file correct and it's ready to upload?

I was getting exact error and found the problem that way.
Also try to use direct upload instead of resumable one, and see if that succeeds.

In java it would be 
`UploadRequest.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);`

It should be similar in .NET too

Comment: Hello Ibrahim, I do not have the option to set 'setDirectUploadEnabled(false)' - also I did not find any setting to do this in the object explorer. The fileStream should work - I do not get any error while debugging - sample code: `code`(    Dim fs As New FileStream(fn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Inheritable)
    fileLen = getFileSize(fn)
    ur = yts.Videos.Insert(meta, "snippet,statistics,status", fs, "application/octet-stream")
    ur.ChunkSize = 100000
    ur.Upload()
    Dim Uploaded = ur.ResponseBody
    fs.Close())

Comment: I just got a working upload if I did the following: Comment out 'meta.Snippet.CategoryId' (cannot find a working one), and setting the ChunkSize to 9999999... but this removes the async feature wich I really would like to keep :/

Comment: I just got it working - enclosed the FIleStream in a BufferedStream and limited the ChunkSize to 12800. Only Problem now is the CategoryID